# Unable to populate RecyclerView adapter with Firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to fetch the data from my Firebase database but from some reason it doesn't work, so I'll try to provide as much info as posible ..

This is the database snapshot:

[image: Database Users]

This is a POJO class:

```
public class Result2 implements Serializable {

private int score;
private String userName;

public Result2(int score, String userName) {
    this.score = score;
    this.userName = userName;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

}
```

This is my activitys layout called activity_results.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="SCORE"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

As you can see, I want to have 2 TextViews that will act like tabs and a RecyclerView underneath that will show the data

Here is my Adapters ViewHolder layout called score_view_holder.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:background="#4545"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
```

So it will contain two horizontal TextViews and a View as a line below..

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class ScoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreAdapter.ScoreViewHolder> {

private List<Result2> results = new ArrayList<>();

public void setResults(List<Result2> results) {
    this.results.clear();
    this.results.addAll(results);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ScoreAdapter.ScoreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.score_view_holder, parent, false);
    return new ScoreAdapter.ScoreViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ScoreAdapter.ScoreViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Result2 result = getResult(position);
    if (result != null) {
        holder.setUsername(result.getUserName() != null ? result.getUserName() : "-");
        holder.setScore(String.valueOf(result.getScore()));
    }
}

private Result2 getResult(int position) {
    return !results.isEmpty() ? results.get(position) : null;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return results.size();
}

public class ScoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView username;
    private TextView score;

    public ScoreViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        score = itemView.findViewById(R.id.score);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username.setText(username);
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score.setText(score);
    }

}
```

}

It should get List of Result2 objects and just set text in those two TextViews (username and score)

And finally my Activity where all the magic doesn't happen :)

```
public class Results extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ScoreAdapter scoreAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Result2> results = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    scoreAdapter = new ScoreAdapter();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    loadResults();
}

private void loadResults() {

    mDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Result2 result =  childSnapshot.getValue(Result2.class);

                if(result != null) {
                    results.add(result);
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(Results.this, String.valueOf(results.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            scoreAdapter.setResults(results);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
}

);
}
}
```

Funniest thing, Toast shows correct number of Results, but when scoreAdapter.setResults(results); is called, screen blinks and goes back to first screen... Does it have something to do with a POJO class, or onDataChange method or main thread?

I tried with debugging and also funny thing here.. This is what is caught on breakpoint inside ScoreAdapter setResult method:

[image: ScoreAdapter setResult() method]

I tried setting breakpoints inside onBindViewHolder and getResults() but none of them gets called :o

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Is results after for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) contain score and username correctly?

Comment: yep.. I tried toasting result.getUserName() in for loop and it showed them correctly

Comment: No error messages, app doesn't even crash, just a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

```
if(result != null) {
     results.add(result);
}
```

See here you are checking `result != null`. But result is a reference variable of type Results. So it will not be null, it will contains some value.

So, try removing that if statement and do only -

```
results.add(result);
```

Comment: still the same :/ just a blank sceeen